# SQL to LINQ - AND Statement in Left Join

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this SQL query to get **all police name that didn't assigned to specified police car**.

```
SELECT policename 
FROM police 
LEFT OUTER JOIN policecar
ON police.policeid = policecar.policeid
AND carid = 1
WHERE policecar.policeid IS NULL
```

I want to convert that query to LINQ but I have difficulty to convert AND and WHERE statement. Please give me any direction on this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result =
    from police in polices
    join policecar in policecars.Where(x => x.carid == 1)
            on police.policeId equals policecar.policeId into res
    where !res.Any()
    select police.policeName;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you don't consider `carid = 1` or am I missed something? I want to change `1` with any `carid` later.